# Which cellular networks stop data when taking phone calls?

Tags: cellular-network, lte

We are developing a mobile application that tracks users while they are picking up and delivering commodities. We have overcome many issues, including poor connectivity in rural areas, the app going into the background, and so on.

One issue continues to befuddle us. When receiving calls some drivers lose connectivity, other drivers will *gain* connectivity, and others (most) have no change in connectivity.

I remember earlier that Verizon iPhone users couldn't access data while on a call. Naively I thought that this issue was completely overcome, but perhaps it is not.

My understanding is that a) there are still some cellular protocols that cannot handle voice and data and b) there are (or were) some settings in mobile phones that give the user a choice.

I have searched for some list of cellular protocols and iOS and Android settings but so far come up empty.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will provide some more clarity; it all depends on the Radio Access Network (RAN) technology they're using (2G/3G/4G) and the terminal itself's capabilities.

There's 3 umbrella terms of technologies, each with their own revisions and variants, but this should cover it:

- **LTE (4G)** only supports voice calls via VoLTE (Voice over LTE).  *Calls made over VoLTE will allow the user to continue accessing data at the same time.* Many devices & some networks don't yet have VoLTE capability, so they use Circuit Switched Fall Back (CSFB) to drop to a 2G/3G Radio Access Network for making voice calls. (If your terminal does this you then have that RAN's ability to allow simultaneous voice/data.)
- **3G** - There's a few flavors of "3G", depending on the terminal and the RAN variant (UMTS / EDGE / CDMA / HSDPA / HSDPA+) you *may* be able to access data and be on a call at the same time.
- **GSM (2G)** does not have this functionality, the handset is either in Circuit Switched (Voice) or Packet Switched (Data) mode but not both.

The decision of which RAN to use is based off the priorities stored in the SIM/USIM, the received signal strength of the available networks and the capabilities of the terminal.

This means for example your users who may *gain* connectivity may find themselves using a 3G access technology on a 4G enabled terminal, with VoLTE support, jumping up to VoLTE to make the call. (Some operators resell to MVNOs but default to slower / older RAN technology like the 3G family)

Others may loose connectivity as you've seen, if they're happily using LTE on a device with no VoLTE support and need to drop to 2G/3G for a call (CSFB) they may loose data services as they're back to the limitations of these older RAN technologies.

Comment: This is a great answer. Often times, even if the device and a network support VoLTE, there might not be support for VoLTE with that particular network and phone combination, and you just end up on CSFB regardless.